# Problems with code to send request and receive response over UART on Atmel SAM L21 Xplained Pro

Tags: arm, embedded, atmel, cortex-m, atmelstudio

I'm currently developing a system which involves sending a request string to a sensor device connected via UART to an Atmel SAML21 Xplained Pro board. I'm testing with an Arduino board as the "sensor device", but eventually, it'll be for a Rotronic HC-2 sensor.

The process goes something like this:

```
MCU sends string { 99RDD} over UART to sensor
-> delay of up to 500ms
-> Response string of 99 bytes sent back via UART
-> Response transmitted to virtual com port on embedded debugger
```

My issue is that for some reason, I'm either not getting anything sent back, or it's sending back the variable **request_msg**

I know that the response from the sensor should be 99 bytes of ASCII, and I've tested both the actual sensor, and the Arduino test board over serial connectors to ensure that the readings are coming back correctly.

The software is using Atmel ASF v4.0, which is great when it works, but the documentation is fairly flaky, so I was hoping someone with more experience could point me as to where I'm going wrong in the code.

I have the following code for my main application:

```
#include "atmel_start.h"
#include "atmel_start_pins.h"
#include <string.h>

static uint8_t example_hello_world[14] = "Hello World!\n";
static uint8_t example_error_msg[13] = "UART Error!\n";
static uint8_t request_msg[24] = "Sending Sensor Request\n";
static uint8_t rotronic_ascii[8] = "{ 99RDD}";

volatile static uint32_t data_arrived = 0;
volatile static uint32_t reading_received = 0;

static void tx_cb_EDBG_COM(const struct usart_async_descriptor *const io_descr)
{
    /* Transfer completed */
    gpio_toggle_pin_level(LED0);
}

static void rx_cb_EDBG_COM(const struct usart_async_descriptor *const io_descr)
{
    /* Receive completed */
    data_arrived = 1;
}

static void err_cb_EDBG_COM(const struct usart_async_descriptor *const io_descr)
{
    /* error handle */
    io_write(&EDBG_COM.io, example_error_msg, 13);
}

static void tx_cb_COM1(const struct usart_async_descriptor *const io_descr)
{
    /* Transfer completed */
    gpio_toggle_pin_level(LED0);
}

static void rx_cb_COM1(const struct usart_async_descriptor *const io_descr)
{
    /* Receive completed */
    reading_received = 1;
}

static void err_cb_COM1(const struct usart_async_descriptor *const io_descr)
{
    /* error handle */
    io_write(&COM1.io, example_error_msg, 13);
}

int main(void)
{
    volatile uint8_t recv_char[99];

    atmel_start_init();

    // Setup the EDBG Serial Port
    usart_async_register_callback(&EDBG_COM, USART_ASYNC_TXC_CB, tx_cb_EDBG_COM);
    usart_async_register_callback(&EDBG_COM, USART_ASYNC_RXC_CB, rx_cb_EDBG_COM);
    usart_async_register_callback(&EDBG_COM, USART_ASYNC_ERROR_CB, err_cb_EDBG_COM);
    usart_async_enable(&EDBG_COM);

    // Send a test string to ensure EDBG Serial is working
    io_write(&EDBG_COM.io, example_hello_world, 14);

    // Setup the Rotronic [Arduino] Serial Port
    usart_async_register_callback(&COM1, USART_ASYNC_TXC_CB, tx_cb_COM1);
    usart_async_register_callback(&COM1, USART_ASYNC_RXC_CB, rx_cb_COM1);
    usart_async_register_callback(&COM1, USART_ASYNC_ERROR_CB, err_cb_COM1);
    usart_async_enable(&COM1);

    while (1) {
        if (reading_received == 0)
        {
            // Delay for a Bit
            delay_ms(5000);

            // Notify the EDBG COM Port
            io_write(&EDBG_COM.io, request_msg, 24);

            // Send the Rotronic ASCII
            io_write(&COM1.io, rotronic_ascii, 8);
        }

        // Check if Reading has been Received
        if (reading_received == 1)
        {
            while (io_read(&COM1.io, &recv_char, 99) == 99)
            {
                // Write what's on the buffer from the receiver
                io_write(&EDBG_COM.io, recv_char, 99);
            }

            // Reset the flag
            reading_received = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: delay_ms(5000) is **not** supposed to wait for half a second

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be coding for ASFv3 - v4 will trigger your receive callback for *any* incoming bytes, not only once when your buffer is full (and you have received every 99 characters).

That means that `io_read` will most probably never return 99 (because it was only a partial read of your message) and you will most probably never send anything back.

Note the [docs](http://start.atmel.com/static/help/index.html?GUID-79201A5A-226F-4FBB-B0B8-AB0BE0554836) say (Scroll down to "different read function behavior..."):

> In ASFv4 a data reception type callback in a driver with a ring buffer is triggered for every received data.

The UART apparently is a driver with a ring buffer.

You need to repeatedly call `io_read` and sum up the number of received bytes until you have got 99. Only then proceed. The ASF docs have an example for that. Make sure you copy code from there that fits your version.

Comment: Do you have a link for that doc? I think I've been looking at old documentation. Also, thanks for the response! Will test out tomorrow and mark this answer as right :)

Comment: Link to quote inserted above.